# 'microsecond' is an invalid keyword argument for replace()

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 2.0+ and am attempting to just plug in the existing password reset function into my website. If the email does not exist, it successfully submits. If it DOES exist, I get this error:

`'microsecond' is an invalid keyword argument for replace()`

I never touched any of the backend code for this function so I would assume it would just work out of the box.

Traceback:

```
C:\Users\djank\documents\github\lfgm_2019\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\djank\documents\github\lfgm_2019\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\djank\documents\github\lfgm_2019\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\djank\documents\github\lfgm_2019\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py in view
            return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\djank\documents\github\lfgm_2019\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py in _wrapper
        return bound_method(*args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\djank\documents\github\lfgm_2019\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py in _wrapped_view
                    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\djank\documents\github\lfgm_2019\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py in dispatch
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\djank\documents\github\lfgm_2019\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py in dispatch
        return handler(request, *args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\djank\documents\github\lfgm_2019\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py in post
            return self.form_valid(form) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\djank\documents\github\lfgm_2019\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py in form_valid
        form.save(**opts) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\djank\documents\github\lfgm_2019\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py in save
                'token': token_generator.make_token(user), …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\djank\documents\github\lfgm_2019\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\tokens.py in make_token
        return self._make_token_with_timestamp(user, self._num_days(self._today())) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\djank\documents\github\lfgm_2019\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\tokens.py in _make_token_with_timestamp
            self._make_hash_value(user, timestamp), …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\djank\documents\github\lfgm_2019\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\tokens.py in _make_hash_value
        login_timestamp = '' if user.last_login is None else user.last_login.replace(microsecond=0, tzinfo=None)
```

I do have a CustomUser model I use, but I can't see if there is a connection or, if so, where the connection might be with that.

Help!

Comment: What's the database type of the last_login column for the user model?

Comment: Which version of Django you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to the `tokens.py` file (for me, it was located here:
`AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\tokens.py` ) and change the following line:

```
user.last_login.replace(microsecond=0,tzinfo=None)
```

to

```
user.last_login.replace()
```

Answer (score 2):

While you can navigate to to tokens.py and modify:

From: `user.last_login.replace(microsecond=0,tzinfo=None)`

To: `user.last_login.replace()`

It's not an ideal solution and has the potential to introduce other unforeseen bugs/errors.

**Better Solution**

A better solution is on your CustomUser model, change any date_joined or last_login (basically date related parameters) to use `DateTimeField` instead of `DateField`. `DateTimeField` includes both the date and time which is what tokens.py is expecting.

Short Example

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email               = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=64, unique=True)
    username            = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True)
    date_joined         = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="date joined", auto_now_add=True)
    last_login          = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="last login", auto_now=True)

    is_admin            = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active           = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff            = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Keep in mind because you are using a CustomUser model, you'll need to add an AccountManger class that handles `create_user()` and `create_superuser()`.